# Assign a smaller df into a bigger df by matching values in a common column

Tags: python, pandas

Assign `small` into `big`, using matching values in the `'c'` column

```
[df] small:
+----+-----+-------+-----+
|    | b   | c     | d   |
|----+-----+-------+-----|
| 22 | zzz | key_1 | zzz |
| 33 | ii  | key_0 | ii  |
+----+-----+-------+-----+

[df] big:
+----+-----+-----+-------+-----+
|    |   a |   b | c     |   d |
|----+-----+-----+-------+-----|
|  0 |   0 |   0 | key_0 |   0 |
|  1 |   0 |   0 | key_1 |   0 |
|  2 |   0 |   0 | 0     |   0 |
|  3 |   0 |   0 | 0     |   0 |
|  4 |   0 |   0 | key_0 |   0 |
+----+-----+-----+-------+-----+

Desired output:
+----+-----+-----+-------+-----+
|    |   a | b   | c     | d   |
|----+-----+-----+-------+-----|
|  0 |   0 | ii  | key_0 | ii  |
|  1 |   0 | zzz | key_1 | zzz |
|  2 |   0 | 0   | 0     | 0   |
|  3 |   0 | 0   | 0     | 0   |
|  4 |   0 | ii  | key_0 | ii  |
+----+-----+-----+-------+-----+
```

It is very temping to feel that a very obvious one liner command should accomplish this, some simple variation of assign or merge would do. Or some magical pandas function I don't know that can just `big.insert(small, by='c')` or something.

However I struggle to come up with a clean elegant solution for this. Everything I come up with is messy and error prone if not careful:

```
# "assign" approach
indexMatcher = small.set_index('c')
for coln in 'bd':
    big.loc[big['c'].isin(small['c']), coln] = big['c'].map(indexMatcher[coln])
    # have to be careful, only assign to a slice of big, otherwise 0s will be overwritten to be nan

# "merge" approach
truthtable = big.c.isin(small.c)
bigslice = big.loc[truthtable, 'c']
merge = pd.merge(bigslice, small, on='c', how='left')
merge.index = bigslice.index # merge destroys original index, have to restore the original index.
big.loc[truthtable, list('bcd')] = merge
```

Starting point:

```
import pandas as pd
big = pd.DataFrame(
{'a': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'b': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'c': {0: 'key_0', 1: 'key_1', 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 'key_0'},
 'd': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}})
small = pd.DataFrame(
{'b': {22: 'zzz', 33: 'ii'},
 'c': {22: 'key_1', 33: 'key_0'},
 'd': {22: 'zzz', 33: 'ii'}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using df.update() will get you the right solution and is faster than iterrows()

You can do it this way as well:

```
big = big.set_index('c')
small = small.set_index('c')
big.update(small)
big.reset_index(inplace=True)
print (big)
```

This will give you:

```
       c  a    b    d
0  key_0  0   ii   ii
1  key_1  0  zzz  zzz
2      0  0    0    0
3      0  0    0    0
4  key_0  0   ii   ii
```

You can do it with iterrows(). However, let me work on a more faster approach.

For now, this will work.

```
for i,x in small.iterrows():
    big.loc[big['c'] == x['c'],'b'] = x['b']
    big.loc[big['c'] == x['c'],'d'] = x['d']
print (big)
```

The output will be:

```
   a    b      c    d
0  0   ii  key_0   ii
1  0  zzz  key_1  zzz
2  0    0      0    0
3  0    0      0    0
4  0   ii  key_0   ii
```

Comment: `df.update()` is the fabled magical function.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to set 'c' as the index for both dataframes and join on the indices:

```
(
    big.set_index("c", append=True)
    .loc[:, ["a"]]
    .join(small.set_index("c"), how="left")
    .reset_index("c")
    .reindex(columns=big.columns)
    .combine_first(big)
)

    a   b      c    d
0   0   ii  key_0   ii
1   0   zzz key_1   zzz
2   0   0      0    0
3   0   0      0    0
4   0   ii  key_0   ii
```

Comment: it is a very nice mental gymnastic, but, I mean we wouldn't do this in real world though right =). It feels so simple, but the answer is so illusive

Comment: in the real world, you would probably break it down, or find a better way to reorganize the data; that way, you have less function calls

Answer (score 1):

Let's do:

```
# Left merge the big dataframe with small
m = big.merge(small, on='c', how='left', suffixes=['', '_r'])

# filter the columns present in only small dataframe
c = m.filter(regex=r'.*(?=_r)')

# Update the filtered dataframe with the values from big dataframe
c.set_axis(c.columns.str.rstrip('_r'), 1).combine_first(big)
```

Result:

```
     a    b      c    d
0  0.0   ii  key_0   ii
1  0.0  zzz  key_1  zzz
2  0.0    0      0    0
3  0.0    0      0    0
4  0.0   ii  key_0   ii
```